# Getting no route matches error despite having "resources" in my config/routes.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes

I"m using Rails 4.2.3 and I’m getting a “No route matches {:action=>"delete", :controller=>"my_objects", :id=>8}” error when I visit my view which contains the below link

```
<%= link_to 'Delete',url_for(controller: 'my_objects', action: :delete,id: my_object_time.my_object.id),method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this data?"} %>
```

However, in my routes/config.rb file, I have included

```
resources :my_objects
```

I even have the method in my my_objects_controller.rb file …

```
  def delete
    my_object.find(params[:id]).destroy
    format.html { redirect_to controller: "users", action: "index", notice: 'Delete successful.' }
  end
```

So I’m not sure why its all falling apart.  Any help is appreciated, - Dave

Comment: `delete` is the correct HTTP verb. The Rails controller action needs to be called `destroy`, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete',url_for(controller: 'my_objects', action: :destroy,id: my_object_time.my_object.id),method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this data?"} %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to 'Delete',  my_object_time.my_object.id,  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```